# Push Notification not working in ios 8.3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, push-notification, ios8.2

My Push Notification is not working in ios 8.3. I had build the project in xcode 6.0 which support upto ios 8.0.   is it the Reason???

Comment: Probably not.  You need to provide more information.  How are you sending the push?  What code do you have in your app? Have you set up the certificates correctly?  Does you app request notification permissions?

Comment: I am sending the Push via parse Server.the Push is Working fine in all version of ios other than ios-8.1,8.2,8.3.

Comment: Do you request permissions as per @manthan's answer?

Comment: Well, to answer the question you will need to run the debugger, which means upgrading to Xcode 6.3, which will rule in/out that as the issue

Comment: Currenty I am upgrading the my xcode to 6.3.  Lets hope it'll work in same......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

// This conditions for ios8 notifications...

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
}
```

Did you put this in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` ???

Put this and check. It should work.

Comment: thankyou so much for reply Gentlemen... I am using the same code and its  working fine with  all version of ios other than ios-8.1,8.2,8.3.

Answer (score 1):

I had found the answer for the Issue...My guess was right that I had build the project in xcode 6.0 which support upto ios 8.0. so Push Notification is not working on the higher version of ios.Now I had upgraded my  xcode upto 6.3 and it support upto latest ios ie 8.3. and My Push is also working fine.thanks for your support guys.