# Push Notification inconsistent. Not working in ios 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, notifications, push-notification

I'm having a similar issue to [Push Notification not working in ios 8.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763060/push-notification-not-working-in-ios-8-3)

The push notifications are being received by 8.1 iphones but those sent to 8.3 iphones are NOT received.

I have updated my xCode to the latest (6.3.1).  That does not seem to be the issue here.

I'm trying to send the push notifications both through the app as well as parse.com. The app does request permission to receive push, but that is not the issue.

This was suggested as a possible solution, though I don't understand where to include it.  I have it included already for stripe.  Though the notifications related to sending users a message that a stripe payment was made isn't working either:

Did you put this in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions ???

Any other suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should receive incoming push notifications in the `-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` method on your application delegate, this is consistently called for applications on cold start and when already running in iOS 7+.

Answer (score 0):

After updating the OS from 8.1 to 8.3, the device token for the app may change. Thats why Apple always suggests to call the

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

every time you open the app. And update the latest device token to your server database.